# Vivaldi fails to load on MATE 20.04

Tags: pi-3b+, vivaldi

I installed the armhf .deb package on Ubuntu MATE 20.04 Focal Fossa.
I tried to run it from the icon in the Menu and it didn't work. So I tried to run from Terminal to see what the issue was.

I ran it from the terminal and got this:

```
[2473:2473:1216/193541.942701:ERROR:chrome_content_client.cc(343)] Failed to locate and load the component updated flash plugin.
[2508:2516:1216/193548.036732:ERROR:nss_util.cc(283)] After loading Root Certs, loaded==false: NSS error code: -8018
../../chromium/sandbox/linux/seccomp-bpf-helpers/sigsys_handlers.cc:**CRASHING**:seccomp-bpf failure in syscall 0403
[2473:2473:1216/193548.596873:ERROR:vivaldi_ui_web_contents_delegate.cc(42)] UI Process abnormally terminates with status 3 after running for 1.87996 seconds!
[2473:2473:1216/193548.684970:ERROR:vivaldi_ui_web_contents_delegate.cc(73)] Quiting Vivaldi
../../chromium/sandbox/linux/seccomp-bpf-helpers/sigsys_handlers.cc:**CRASHING**:seccomp-bpf failure in syscall 0403
```

I've used this before on Raspberry Pi OS (previously called Raspbian) with no issues, but I switched over to Ubuntu MATE and now I'm having trouble.

Comment: This would actually be better on the Linux or Ubuntu forum though I think you already have posted this on the Vivaldi support forum?  Voting close as its being asked in a better place.

Comment: I posted this to the Ubuntu MATE community and the Vivaldi Forums. I post on multiple websites to increase my chances of a response for a solution.

Comment: "I post on multiple websites to" waste more people's time.

Comment: @Milliways When there is no answer everywhere, the waste of time is to ask everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

same for me! no problem with Raspbian but to run Vivaldi on my Raspbyerry PI 4 on Ubuntu Mate 20.10 (amrhf 32 bit) I have to launch it this way:
vivaldi --disable-seccomp-filter-sandbox

I've found the solution here: https://forum.vivaldi.net/topic/53399/crashing-seccomp-bpf-failure-in-syscall-0403-rpi4-8gb-ubuntu20-10-arm64-armhf